# Add a drop down suggestion below a UISearchbar and UITextfields

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uisearchbar

In my ios app, there are 3 separate text entry fields. One in a Searchbar and two in a UIAlertview(that has two entry fields). I need to give a drop down menu below the fields that can give the suggestions to the user. I have the data needed in an array(all 3 fields need the same array for suggestion). How would I do this?  Should I programmatically create a UITableView that would appear below all the TextFields(with the most basic cell, containing one text field) ? If So, how can I get the right frame? Or else, what other method should I refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example. Here i am taking one UITextField. When it becomes first responder, i am showing the drop down i.e., UITableView . When an object selected from the table view the drop down will collapse.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


   mutArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object1"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object2"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object3"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object4"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object5"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object6"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object7"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"object8"];


   txtList1=[[UITextField alloc]init];
   [txtList1 setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 260, 30)];
   [txtList1 setTag:100];
   [txtList1 setDelegate:self];
   [txtList1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
   [txtList1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   [self.view addSubview:txtList1];

   tblList=[[UITableView alloc]init];
   [tblList setDelegate:self];
   [tblList setDataSource:self];
   [self.view addSubview:tblList];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return mutArr.count;
}


  -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
   [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
   cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
   cell.textLabel.text=[mutArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   return cell;

 }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tblList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   txtList1.text=cell.textLabel.text;

   [txtList1 resignFirstResponder];
   [self collapseTableView];


}


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];

   if (textField.tag==100)
   {
       CGRect rect=tblList.frame;
       if (rect.size.height==0)
       {
          [self expandTableView];

       }
   }

}


-(void)collapseTableView
{

   [tblList setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 130, 260, 120)];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{

       [tblList setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 130, 260, 0)];

    }
   completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
       NSLog(@"comleted");
    }];

}

-(void)expandTableView
{
   [tblList setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 130, 260, 0)];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{

      [tblList setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 130, 260, 200)];

    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
       NSLog(@"comleted");
    }];

}
```

Comment: One major problem still remains for me..the UITextField inside UIAlertView does not call the methods - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

Comment: Do you need to show every thing in UIAlertView..??  How you are adding textFields to the AlertView..??