# How to set a recent search history drop down for UISearchBar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to set a recent search history dropdown for **`UISearchbar`** . I have implemented a dropdown programatically using a `UITableView`

**Logic:**
How i have implemented is by setting a `UITableView` right below the `UISearchBar` and on click on the `UISearchBar` it will pop up .
Am initially hiding that tableview in `viewdidload` and in 
`-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` am unhiding the tableview . 
Iam facing too many problems with this :

**1.** The return button is not enabled when the `searchbartext` is empty .In that case if i have to cancel/hide the table view again i have to depend on `tapgestures` .

**2.** Clicking on the `searchbartext` again won't trigger any of its delegates. The only time it triggers the delegates on click on the `searchbartext` is when click on it for the first time then it calls         `-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`

Do u guys have any other solution / way to implement this feature in a much better way than this ?? 
Do we have any custom made `UISearchBar` recent history dropdowns ??
I have searched for a custom `UISearchBar` recent history dropdown in `cocoacontrols`,`code4app` and `cocoapods` for this no hope dint find any . 
Please help me with this .

Answer (score 1):

For your **first issue**, you can add a category on `UISearchBar` something like this and this shall always enable your `return` button on keyboard when tapped on `UISearchBar`

```
@implementation UISearchBar (MyAddition)


- (void)alwaysEnableSearch {
    // Loop around subviews of UISearchBar
    NSMutableSet *viewsToCheck = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[self subviews]];

    while ([viewsToCheck count] > 0) {
        UIView *searchBarSubview = [viewsToCheck anyObject];
        [viewsToCheck addObjectsFromArray:searchBarSubview.subviews];
        [viewsToCheck removeObject:searchBarSubview];

    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
        @try {
            // Force return key to be enabled
            [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
        }
        @catch (NSException *iException) {

        }
    }
  }
}
```

For **second issue**, why don't you use `shouldChangeTextInRange:` delegate method which gets called for each entered character.

As a side note, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814688/add-a-drop-down-suggestion-below-a-uisearchbar-and-uitextfields) has a sample code to do this. This may help you.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks :) For the second issue the way i want to tackle is when the searchbartextfield is empty and i click on the searchbartextfield second time i want to dismiss the tableview . Thats why am not using shouldChangeTextInRange delegate method .

Comment: I see. Did you try `touchesBegan:` method?  It should get called when you touch the search bar because its super class is `UIResponder`. Also, I think this answers deserves an upvote :)!

Comment: :-) Thank you. Let me know if you are able to figure it out using `touchesBegan:`. I will be happy to invest time and help you out, if not.

Answer (score 0):

I am re-writing the possible steps as per your recent clarification.

1. keep a *flag/boolean* to monitor tableview is hidden or not.
2. in the UISearchBar Delegate method check the serachbar's text field's [obj isFirstResponder] method.
   a. if *firstResponder* =yes --> Show the histroy tableview OR Vice versa.After show/hide is accomplished call below method on UISearchBar' textfield.
     *[*searchbarobj*.*textfield* *resignFirstResponder*];*
   b. if *firstResponder* = No---> Don't do anything. leave the method.

Comment: i can explain you the scenario . Suppose i clicked on the searchbartextfield it will trigger the delegates but again another click on the searchbartextfield doesn't trigger the delegates . Thats my problem .

Comment: you want to show/hide tableview on tap of searchbar..right ?

Comment: Yes exactly . I want to implement the same with a return key in keyboard but sadly the return key is disable when there is no text entry in UISearchBar .